# latexmk with xelatex xdv mode

Tags: xetex, latexmk

I want to know how to use latexmk with xelatex **and** tell it to write to xdv file a number of times until all the references are correct, then use `xdvipdfmx` once to generate the final output. This is practical because for manuscripts with a lot of figures and references and needs several passes to get all the references right, writing to xdv files are way, way faster than writing to pdf every pass.

Comment: Could you quantify the improvement in execution time from making an xdv file instead of a pdf file.

Comment: @JohnCollins For my 100+ pages thesis with a lot of eps figures, making a pdf takes about 10 minutes, while xdv finishes in a minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Important update to old answer

The old answer (below) was appropriate when it was written (in April 2014), but it uses a nasty trick. Since then, changes in `latexmk`'s support of `xelatex` were made, starting in v. 4.52. `Latexmk` now does exactly what the question asked for, without any special configuration. For details, see the `latexmk` documentation, in the explanations of the option `-pdfxe` and the variable `$xelatex`.

So if you invoke a current version of `latexmk` by `latexmk -pdfxe` or `latexmk -xelatex`, it will now do exactly what was asked.

### Old Answer

With the present `latexmk`, a simple trick is to arrange to treat this by the dvi-pdf route for making `pdf` files.   You do this by getting the 'xdv' file copied to a 'dvi' file.  The following lines in an initialization file implement this:

```perl
$pdf_mode = 3;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
$latex = 'xelatex --no-pdf %O %S && cp %Z%R.xdv %D';
$dvipdf = 'xdvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
$clean_full_ext .= ' xdv';
```

The definition of `$latex` is appropriate for UNIX-like operating systems (e.g., linux and OS-X), and will need to be changed for MS-Windows.

Given the improved performance by this method, I should enhance `latexmk` to do it properly, with a `-pdfxdv` option in addition to its current `-pdfdvi` option.

### Notes

The tail `&& cp %Z%R.xdv %D` of the command line defined in `$latex` uses an idiom of the `sh`/`bash` shells: The part to the right of the `&&` is run only if the command on the left (i.e., `xelatex`) succeeded.  The `cp` part does the copying (under UNIX-type operating systems) of the `xdv` file to the `dvi` file.  %Z denotes the output directory with any necessary trailing separator, %R denotes the rootname of the 'tex' file, and %D denotes the destination file, i.e., the `dvi` file; these will be replaced by the correct values by `latexmk`, as explained in its documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on the `&& cp %Z%R.xdv` part?

Comment: @davidsedai: I've added some comments.