# "xelatex" command does not work (driver returns error -1073741571) but "xelatex --no-pdf" followed by "xdvipdfmx " works

Tags: xetex, miktex, xdvipdfmx

I am using XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit) in a docker container with Windows Server 2016.

When I run the command `xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode test.tex` I obtain this error: `Error -1073741571 (driver return code) generating output; file test.pdf may not be valid.` and no pdf is generated.

However when I run `xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode --no-pdf test.tex` and then `xdvipdfmx test.xdv` (what is perfectly equivalent according to this post: [Generating PDF from xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401464/generating-pdf-from-xelatex?rq=1)), it works.

For certain reasons, I would like to make it work in one single command.
I don't have any other relevant information in any log files (in the log files I know).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you try bisecting your document to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, please?

Comment: Here is the latex code: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
TEST
\end{document}
`

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be something more complicated than that. Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem with TeXLive.

Comment: You could enable tracing to find out more. My guess would be that MiKTeX has problems to  write or use the intermediate temporary file.

Comment: try `xelatex -output-driver='xdvipdfmx -E'` (so not `-q`) then the internal call to xdvipdfmx will log errors to the terminal