# latexmk preview xdv file?

Tags: xetex, latexmk, xdvipdfmx, xdvi

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169027/latexmk-with-xelatex-xdv-mode) introduced a idea that instead of generating pdf file every time, we may use xdv file as the target for intermediate processes, and only convert to pdf file once with `xdvipdfmx` at the final step, and this is expected to save us a lot of processing time.

And also quote from the manual of latexmk:

> **-pdfxe** Generate  pdf  version of document using xelatex.  Note that to optimize processing time, latexmk uses xelatex to generate an xdv file rather than a pdf file directly. Only after possibly multiple runs to generate a fully up-to-date xdv does latexmk then call xdvipdfmx to generate the final pdf file.
>
> (Note: When the document includes large graphics files, especially png files, the last step can be quite time consuming, even when the creation  of  the  xdv  file  by xelatex  is  fast.  So the use of the intermediate xdv file can result in substantial gains in procesing time, since the pdf file is produced once rather than on every run of xelatex.)

I am thinking of if there is way to fully utilize this feature. Currently when I edit a tex file, I would always have `latexmk -xelatex -pvc` run somewhere so that I can see the updated file immediately. But this command would still generate the pdf file at each run(after each time I saved the file). So are there actually ways that let latexmk generate only the `xdv` file? And I would manually convert the xdv file to pdf after I finish editing.

But of course I am just searching for a more efficient workflow, what I am suggesting here may not be the optimal as well. If there are other ways to save the processing time, please let me know!

Comment: `xetex --no-pdf` will make just the xdv and not the pdf, but is there a viewer that can preview xdv files?

Comment: yes, skim on mac opens xdv files. I am not sure if it converts xdv to pdf internally tho. So is it actually a good idea to reducing processing time by only generating xdv file?

Comment: @huangzonghao Skim just calls `xdvipdfmx` when you ask it to open an XDV file. I think it should be possible to have `latexmk` call `xelatex` with `-no-pdf` and, when the last run is successful, call `xdvipdfmx`. Indeed, for graphic intensive documents this could result in faster compilation.

Comment: for most documents you should never have to do multiple runs while in an edit-preview cycle, so unless you are happy to do lots of editing and just run `xetex -no-pdf` to syntax check without viewing the result, I don't see how this can speed things up.

Comment: @egreg Oh yeah, if skim is also calling `xdvipdfmx` I guess there would be no point for me to try to stop latexmk from doing so. And as a side note, I think latexmk only passes command of `pdflatex`? So `-draftmode` works for `pdflatex`, but `--no-pdf` will not be passed to `xetex`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Now I also think it won't actually save much time.